# Bootstrap toast apears behind elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, toast

I've got the following problem. I want the toast o appear on the bottom right and its working but it appear behind other text:

[image: Toast image]

This Is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="toast" id="recipeLike" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" auto-hide="false" data-delay="2000" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; right: 0;">
    <div class="toast-header">
        <strong class="mr-auto"><i class="fas fa-heart text-danger"></i> We miss you!</strong>
        <small>11 mins ago</small>
        <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="toast-body">
        <div>It's been a long time since you visited us. We've something special for you. <a href="#">Click here!</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Adding z-index: -1; does not work, it moves all the elements. What should I do, any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding `z-index: 99` to `.toastr` and check the z-index of social icons. Other possibility is to check the background color of the toastr

Comment: Yes I add 9998, now it works.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped. Can you please mark my comment as useful?